# How to use react-jss with MaterialUI 4?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss, css-in-js

I've used `react-jss` with `material-ui` for a while now. The material-ui 3.x -> 4.x migration guide says that MUI 4 isn't compatible with React JSS 9.x:

https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/

Furthermore, it looks like the `react-jss` project has been archived:

https://github.com/cssinjs/react-jss

...but JSS is up to at least version 10:

https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.16

So I'm completely confused on how to use React-JSS with MUI 4. Is the import something other than `"react-jss": "8.6.1",` in `package.json`? Should I switch to Emotion or Styled Components? So confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
"react-jss": "10.0.0-alpha.16"
```

https://github.com/cssinjs/react-jss is archived because of it being restructured to be part of the jss monorepo (multiple packages in one GitHub repository): https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/tree/master/packages/react-jss.

Whenever you upgrade Material-UI, you should check to see if the jss version in Material-UI has changed so that you can stay in sync; otherwise you'll be pulling in two versions of jss. You can check the Material-UI jss version here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui-styles/package.json#L48

You should also look into whether you need to be using react-jss directly vs. just using the jss wrappers in Material-UI (e.g. `withStyles`, `makeStyles`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. There are plenty of places in my code where I use `react-jss` outside of the context of Material-UI. Maybe there's a way in the long run for me to collapse everything down to a single way of doing things, but for now I need both ways.

Comment: Ryan, one more question. As I learn a little more about MUIv4, it sort of seems like I should abandon `react-jss` entirely and replace it with `@material-ui/styles`. It seems like it would be more or less a drop-in replacement, right? I can still use JSS syntax in that case, and I can use `@material-ui/styles` to styles non-MUI elements, if I'm understanding things right. Right?

Comment: Correct. That’s what I was referring to at the end of my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. Just took a little bit to get this horse to drink. (-;